# Dictionary in Python - checking for key

Tags: python

Here is the code that I wrote so far:

```
def Ordinal(check):
    data={1:"First", 2:"Second", 3:"Third", 4:"Fourth", 5:"Fifth", 6:"Sixth", 7:"Seventh", 8:"Eighth", 9:"Ninth", 10:"Tenth", 11:"Eleventh", 12:"Twelfth"}

    if check in dict.keys: 
        return dict.get(check)
    else:
        return""
def main():
    Num=input("Enter a number (1-12) to get its ordinal: ")
    print ("The ordinal is", Ordinal(Num))
main()
```

The program is suppose to get a number between 1 to 12 from the user and then print its ordinal. I am having trouble using the input and checking to see if it is a key and then returning its value as a print statement in the main function. The error is related to the if statement.

Comment: Side-note: It would be best to make the `dict` outside of `Ordinal`; as is, it gets rebuilt every call, which is rather silly. For one call, doesn't matter, but I'm assuming the code will scale up at some point?

Comment: We love stack traces here. _" The error is related to the if statement."_ is vague compared to the detail python gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with `if check in data.keys:` because:

`data.keys` is a method: `<built-in method keys of dict object at 0x10b989280>`

You should call the method `data.keys()` which returns `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`

Or you can do:

```
def Ordinal(check):
    data={1:"First", 2:"Second", 3:"Third", 4:"Fourth", 5:"Fifth", 6:"Sixth", 7:"Seventh", 8:"Eighth", 9:"Ninth", 10:"Tenth", 11:"Eleventh", 12:"Twelfth"}

    if check in data:
        return data.get(check)
    else:
        return""
def main():
    Num=input("Enter a number (1-12) to get its ordinal: ")
    print ("The ordinal is", Ordinal(Num))
main()
```

Or as @astrosyam pointed out, using `data.get(int(check), "")` is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 3):

Try this ...

```
def Ordinal(check):
    data={1:"First", 2:"Second", 3:"Third", 4:"Fourth", 5:"Fifth", 6:"Sixth", 7:"Seventh", 8:"Eighth", 9:"Ninth", 10:"Tenth", 11:"Eleventh", 12:"Twelfth"}
    return data.get(int(check), "")

def main():
    Num=input("Enter a number (1-12) to get its ordinal: ")
    print ("The ordinal is", Ordinal(Num))
main()
```

The if check is not necessary since dict.get can return a default value.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Bryan Oakley's answer you can do the following:

```
def Ordinal(check):
    data={1:"First", 2:"Second", 3:"Third", 4:"Fourth", 5:"Fifth", 6:"Sixth", 7:"Seventh", 8:"Eighth", 9:"Ninth", 10:"Tenth", 11:"Eleventh", 12:"Twelfth"}

    if check in data:
        return data.get(check)
    else:
        return""
def main():
    Num=eval(input("Enter a number (1-12) to get its ordinal: ")) #notice eval here!
    print ("The ordinal is", Ordinal(Num))
main()
```

Notice that I added the eval by the input line.

Comment: And this is kids, is how you add security holes on purpose. In his case int() would be suitable for both validating input and enforcing type of data, while eval opens can of worms allowing arbitrary execution of anything.

Comment: precisely what kind of error are you worried about with eval?

Comment: eval() by itself isn't dangerous but it becomes one when combined with untrusted input and privilege escalation.

Comment: I guess I don't see in this example where that would be the case. I understand your point however

Comment: I just think that practice of using eval() should be discouraged from the start. And yes, in this case it's probably fine to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Don't print the output if they input an invalid key.

```
data = {
    1: "First", 2: "Second", 3: "Third", 4: "Fourth", 5: "Fifth",
    6: "Sixth", 7: "Seventh", 8: "Eighth", 9: "Ninth", 10: "Tenth",
    11: "Eleventh", 12: "Twelfth"}


def Ordinal(check):
    return data[check]


def main():
    Num = input("Enter a number (1-12) to get its ordinal: ")

    try:
        print ("The ordinal is {}".format(Ordinal(int(Num))))
    except ValueError:
        print("didnt enter a valid integer")
    except KeyError:
        print("Not number between 1-12")

main()
```

If using python 2.x use `raw_input` instead of `input`.